# Read dot graph in networkx from a string and not file

Tags: python-2.7, graph, networkx

As per the [documentation here](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.read_dot.html) the `read_dot()` method takes a file handle as an input.

Even it works fine if I do,

```
g = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.read_dot(dotFile)
```

where `dotFile` is the file handle. However if I have `dot` formatted graph in a variable, how can I import in nx graph format?

Edit - 
My variable looks like this,

```
dotFormat = """
digraph G{
edge [dir=forward]
node [shape=plaintext]
0 [label="0 (None)"]
0 -> 7 [label="root"]
1 [label="1 (The)"]
4 [label="4 (great Indian Circus)"]
4 -> 4 [label="compound"]
4 -> 1 [label="det"]
4 -> 4 [label="amod"]
5 [label="5 (is)"]
6 [label="6 (in)"]
7 [label="7 (Mumbai)"]
7 -> 6 [label="case"]
7 -> 5 [label="cop"]
7 -> 4 [label="nsubj"]
}
"""
```

EDIT 2 -  I also tried reading with `py_dot` and then converting to networkx graph like this.

```
pg = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dotFormat)
g = nx.nx_pydot.from_pydot(pg)
```

Then I get following error

```
if P.get_strict(None): # pydot bug: get_strict() shouldn't take argument
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_strict'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using pygraphviz explicitly to load the graph and then convert it to a networkx graph (a MultiDiGraph in this case).

```
In [1]: import pygraphviz

In [2]: from networkx.drawing import nx_agraph

In [3]: dotFormat = """
digraph G{
edge [dir=forward]
node [shape=plaintext]
0 [label="0 (None)"]
0 -> 7 [label="root"]
1 [label="1 (The)"]
4 [label="4 (great Indian Circus)"]
4 -> 4 [label="compound"]
4 -> 1 [label="det"]
4 -> 4 [label="amod"]
5 [label="5 (is)"]
6 [label="6 (in)"]
7 [label="7 (Mumbai)"]
7 -> 6 [label="case"]
7 -> 5 [label="cop"]
7 -> 4 [label="nsubj"]
}
"""

In [4]: G = nx_agraph.from_agraph(pygraphviz.AGraph(dotFormat))
```

Answer (score 2):

graph_from_dot_data actually returns a list of graph.

So just use a single element from it